# NSlog returns NULL for NSMutableDictionary from different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Really confused with why this is not working.

PracticeTeamSelection.m

```
NSLog(@"Practice Roster : %@", practiceRoster);
```

PracticeActual.m

```
PracticeTeamSelection *teamSelectionViewController = [[PracticeTeamSelection alloc]init];

NSLog(@"practice List : %@", [teamSelectionViewController practiceRoster]);
```

So practiceRoster is an NSMutableDictionary, and when i run the first bit of code I am returned exactly what i am supposed to be, however when i run the next bit of code in PracticeActual.m it returns (Null).

in my PracticeTeamSelection in the .h I do the following with the proper synthesize

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *practiceRoster;
```

and in the PracticeActual.m in include

```
#import "PracticeTeamSelection.h"
```

But maybe it is being release somewhere with out my knowledge. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Do you set `practiceRoster` in the `init` method of PracticeTeamSelection.m?

Comment: no i do not, should I?  Also by init method would viewdidload be acceptable?

Comment: Probably. But this is why the result is `NULL`. The dictionary has been allocated and initialized, but no content has been set.

Comment: In the .h of PracticeTeamSelection i do NSMutableDictionary *practiceRoster; and  @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *practiceRoster;

Comment: could you give me an example of how i would "set" practiceRoster?

Comment: but it does return me content when i access it from PracticeTeamSelection, just not when i try to look at it from PracticeActual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one PracticeTeamSelection object where practiceRoster is set to something. But in your PracticeActual class, when you write `[[PracticeTeamSelection alloc]init]`, you're creating **another** PracticeTeamSelection object. The new object has nothing to do with the other one that has its practiceRoster set, no more than all your NSString objects have the same content.

Comment: hmm, well then how would I write the code to let me get at the practiceRoster that is inside the PracticeTeamSelection class?

Comment: @James Dunay: That's totally a matter of how your program is structured. If they're in the same nib, you just draw a connection between them. If they both know about some common object (e.g. the app delegate or the current document), you can have that object at as an intermediary. If there's some object that knows about both of them, again, you can have that object hook things up.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't actually created a dictionary anywhere. You just defined a property. All properties on an object start out with their zero value — for objects, this is nil.

Comment: but i have created a dictionary, in the .h i have the following  NSMutableDictionary *practiceRoster; and @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *practiceRoster;

Comment: You declared the dictionary. You haven't actually created anything at all. In essence, you now have a dictionary-shaped slot that's sitting empty. You need to fill it by actually putting a dictionary in there, e.g. `self.practiceRoster = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`. This is frequently done within your `-init` method.